Make openalpr's alpr.exe config accept unicode letters (or utf8)
How to set a config in alpr.exe directory so that it acceps unicode or utf8 letters and numbers?
for example for the eu config There is:
postprocess_regex_letters = [A-Z]
postprocess_regex_numbers = [0-9]

is replacing letters and numbers with dot (.) sufficient?
